# How can I add or do some multiplcations and let my user change their CharField values in Django Application

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I need an Explanation and Advice to make my small project like I would given my users "money, not real money just some numbers" and let them spend on my items and I need a way to know how can I make the money usable on the money they have like addition the money amount and subtraction on the amount of their money, I need an Advice and Explanation please.

I've tried to do these things and they are not working, my mind is blowing and I need help

Comment: Can you convert your question to a specific problem that you are facing? What part of the logic are you confused with?

Comment: I have a profile model and in that model I have money CharField, I'll give my user some money and let them increase their money by clicking on the button I'll create, I hope you realise my problem sir, It'll look like click to earn money

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to "UPDATE" the field money in your model.
Create a forms.py with the field money.
Create the view to edit the form with the field money.
Update your urls.py to have the view.
In the template the post button for your urls function.
This is the flow concept to build in django.